# Triples of primes satisfying a certain equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p,q,r$ be primes satisfying $p(q-1)=r-1$. The question is: are there infinitely many of such prime triples $(p,q,r)$? Manual inspection gives plenty of examples: $(2,2,3),(2,3,5),(3,7,19),(5,7,31), (7,5,29)$ and many more. It looks that there are indeed an infinite number of them. But how to prove it? Maybe fixing $p$ or $q$ and reduce it to certain *pairs*, rather than triples?

Comment: The Bunyakovsky-conjecture implies your conjecture. If we fix a prime $q$, then the polynomials $p$ and $(q-1)\cdot p+1$ share no common factor. Bunyakovsky's conjectures expects infinite many $p$, such that both $p$ and $(q-1)\cdot p+1$ are prime.

Comment: Ah! Did not know about this conjecture. Thanks! Have there been attempts to prove the conjecture?

Comment: I don't know but I think it was attempted. By the way, choosing $q=3$, we only need infinite many primes $p$, such that $2p+1$ is prime as well. This is also not proven, but very likely to be true.

Comment: @Especially Lime - why did you delete your answer - it is part of the insights!

Comment: In fact, I remembered it wrong and though it would be a pair $(p/2p-1)$

Comment: Even better If for infinite many primes $q$, there exist ONE prime $p$, such that $p\cdot (q-1)+1$ is prime or similar for infinite many primes $p$, there exist ONE prime $q$ , such that $p\cdot (q-1)+1$ is prime, then your conjecture is already true, so it is a far weaker statement than the Bunyakovsky-conjecture and related conjectures.

Comment: @Peter, I'd just like to call your attention to my community wiki answer below; you might find it of interest.

Comment: @BarryCipra I could help searching the "omitted" primes if that would help.

Comment: @Peter, a friend reports having found $311$ omitted primes (out of $1228$ odd primes in all) less than $10{,}000$.  If he sends me the list in a form I can easily add to the wiki, I'll do so. But if you get there (or beyond) first, please do so.

Comment: @BarryCipra I updated my answer : A much better method to determine "omitted" primes. The counting of the "omitted" primes is not very promising. If "omitted" primes were rare, the conjecture would get an additional strong evidence to be true. But this does not seem to be the case.

Comment: $\color\red {2\ 507\ 124}$ "omitted" primes below $10^8$ out of $\color\green {5\ 761\ 454}$ odd primes

Comment: $\color\red {23\ 794\ 968}$ "omitted" primes below $10^9$ out of $\color\green {50\ 847\ 533}$ odd primes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you fix $q=3$ then the values of $p$ which work are the [Sophie Germain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain_prime) primes. There are conjectured to be infinitely many of those, but no proof is known. I suspect your more general question is of comparable difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

If you take q to be an odd number >1 (not necessarely prime), then $k=q-1$ is even and the equation becomes:

$k.p= r-1$ or $k.p +1=r$

So the question then becomes: Are there for every even $k$, infinitely many prime numbers $p$ and $r$ such that $r=k.p+1$ ?

Sort of generalisation of Sophie Germain primes, where $k=2$.

Answer (score 1):

This is more comment than answer, but it might be of interest.  Systematically considering all odd primes $r$ less than $100$, I find that $r-1$ can be written in the form $p(q-1)$ with primes $p$ and $q$ for all $r$ except $r=17$, $41$, $89$, and $97$.  (E.g., $89-1=88$ has only $p=2$ and $p=11$ as possible prime factors, but $88=2(45-1)$ and $88=11(9-1)$ give composites for $q$.) If I haven't made any mistakes, the sequence of "omitted" primes does not (at the moment) appear in the OEIS.  Sequence [A087877](http://oeis.org/A087877) starts out $17,41,89,97,233,257,281,\ldots$. By happenstance (or otherwise), $233$ and $257$ are also "omitted" (e.g., $257-1=2^8=2(3\cdot43-1)$), but $281-1=280=7(41-1)$ is not.

The OP's conjecture is that infinitely many primes $r$ satisfy $r-1=p(q-1)$ for some primes $p$ and $q$. As pointed by Peter and Especially Lime, this conjecture is a simple consequence of other well known conjectures.  A related question would be whether there are infinitely many "omitted" primes $r$ (and if so, how dense they are among the primes). The coincidence that two out of the next three primes at A087877 are omitted suggests that omitted primes become common. However, it might just be a coincidence.

I'm making this community wiki so that others can extend (or correct) the sequence of "omitted" primes to

$$17,41,89,97,101,137,\ldots$$

(with $r=151$ as the largest prime currently checked).

**Added later**:  [Brian Hayes](http://bit-player.org) reports $311$ "omitted" primes up to $10{,}000$ (out of $1228$ odd primes altogether):

$$17, 41, 89, 97, 101, 137, 163, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 271, 353, 401, 433, 443, 449, 461, 569, 601, 641, 647, 659, 809, 821, 827, 857, 881, 929, 941, 1013, 1033, 1049, 1061, 1097, 1129, 1151, 1171, 1181, 1193, 1217, 1223, 1259, 1277, 1289, 1361, 1409, 1429, 1433, 1451, 1489, 1499, 1601, 1609, 1697, 1787, 1847, 1871, 1889, 1913, 1973, 1999, 2003, 2069, 2081, 2087, 2141, 2153, 2243, 2273, 2297, 2333, 2339, 2351, 2357, 2377, 2381, 2393, 2521, 2531, 2539, 2617, 2621, 2633, 2657, 2663, 2687, 2689, 2699, 2713, 2741, 2753, 2777, 2789, 2791, 2833, 2843, 2861, 2969, 3041, 3049, 3109, 3169, 3191, 3209, 3299, 3331, 3389, 3449, 3461, 3469, 3529, 3581, 3593, 3613, 3617, 3659, 3673, 3719, 3761, 3767, 3769, 3793, 3821, 3833, 3851, 3911, 3917, 3929, 3943, 4001, 4013, 4019, 4049, 4073, 4153, 4231, 4241, 4289, 4421, 4451, 4457, 4483, 4637, 4649, 4673, 4721, 4729, 4793, 4877, 4889, 4903, 4931, 4937, 4943, 4973, 4993, 5021, 5051, 5153, 5171, 5209, 5237, 5261, 5273, 5279, 5281, 5351, 5381, 5417, 5441, 5449, 5501, 5563, 5651, 5779, 5801, 5861, 5881, 5903, 6029, 6043, 6053, 6089, 6113, 6221, 6257, 6263, 6287, 6299, 6301, 6329, 6359, 6449, 6469, 6473, 6491, 6529, 6551, 6563, 6569, 6571, 6577, 6673, 6793, 6857, 6863, 6869, 6917, 6959, 6971, 6977, 7001, 7019, 7043, 7121, 7151, 7297, 7349, 7369, 7433, 7451, 7457, 7481, 7487, 7529, 7541, 7547, 7549, 7577, 7583, 7639, 7649, 7681, 7723, 7817, 7829, 7841, 7867, 7877, 7883, 7907, 7919, 7993, 8017, 8081, 8087, 8089, 8093, 8161, 8219, 8233, 8237, 8243, 8273, 8377, 8387, 8501, 8609, 8627, 8641, 8663, 8669, 8693, 8803, 8821, 8837, 8861, 8929, 8951, 8969, 9007, 9011, 9041, 9059, 9091, 9127, 9157, 9203, 9209, 9221, 9239, 9257, 9281, 9293, 9323, 9337, 9341, 9343, 9377, 9397, 9419, 9431, 9461, 9479, 9497, 9551, 9623, 9629, 9631, 9677, 9689, 9767, 9791, 9803, 9833, 9851, 9859, 9923, 9941,\ldots$$

In a separate answer (which I only just now saw), Peter has taken things out to $20{,}000$, giving $597$ omitted primes (out of $2261$ odd primes to that point). The density of omitted primes, if there is one, seems to be creeping up.

Comment: I think larger primes will be more and more likely to be "omitted". But infinite many "non-omitted" primes are enough. Nevertheless, this approach is not likely to give a strong evidence of the truth of the conjecture. This would be the case, if the "omitted" primes would be rare.

Answer (score 1):

Upto $20\ 000$, we have the following $597$ "omitted" primes

```
? z=0;forprime(r=3,20000,gef=0;forprime(p=1,r,forprime(q=1,ceil(r/p),if(gef==0,i
f(p*(q-1)==r-1,gef=1))));if(gef==0,z=z+1;print1(r," ")));print;print(z)
17 41 89 97 101 137 163 233 239 241 251 257 271 353 401 433 443 449 461 569 601
641 647 659 809 821 827 857 881 929 941 1013 1033 1049 1061 1097 1129 1151 1171
1181 1193 1217 1223 1259 1277 1289 1361 1409 1429 1433 1451 1489 1499 1601 1609
1697 1787 1847 1871 1889 1913 1973 1999 2003 2069 2081 2087 2141 2153 2243 2273
2297 2333 2339 2351 2357 2377 2381 2393 2521 2531 2539 2617 2621 2633 2657 2663
2687 2689 2699 2713 2741 2753 2777 2789 2791 2833 2843 2861 2969 3041 3049 3109
3169 3191 3209 3299 3331 3389 3449 3461 3469 3529 3581 3593 3613 3617 3659 3673
3719 3761 3767 3769 3793 3821 3833 3851 3911 3917 3929 3943 4001 4013 4019 4049
4073 4153 4231 4241 4289 4421 4451 4457 4483 4637 4649 4673 4721 4729 4793 4877
4889 4903 4931 4937 4943 4973 4993 5021 5051 5153 5171 5209 5237 5261 5273 5279
5281 5351 5381 5417 5441 5449 5501 5563 5651 5779 5801 5861 5881 5903 6029 6043
6053 6089 6113 6221 6257 6263 6287 6299 6301 6329 6359 6449 6469 6473 6491 6529
6551 6563 6569 6571 6577 6673 6793 6857 6863 6869 6917 6959 6971 6977 7001 7019
7043 7121 7151 7297 7349 7369 7433 7451 7457 7481 7487 7529 7541 7547 7549 7577
7583 7639 7649 7681 7723 7817 7829 7841 7867 7877 7883 7907 7919 7993 8017 8081
8087 8089 8093 8161 8219 8233 8237 8243 8273 8377 8387 8501 8609 8627 8641 8663
8669 8693 8803 8821 8837 8861 8929 8951 8969 9007 9011 9041 9059 9091 9127 9157
9203 9209 9221 9239 9257 9281 9293 9323 9337 9341 9343 9377 9397 9419 9431 9461
9479 9497 9551 9623 9629 9631 9677 9689 9767 9791 9803 9833 9851 9859 9923 9941
10061 10133 10139 10169 10181 10193 10223 10247 10253 10267 10313 10337 10427 10
429 10433 10457 10501 10513 10529 10601 10657 10753 10781 10847 10889 10937 1094
9 10993 11027 11059 11093 11159 11261 11273 11287 11311 11351 11369 11393 11447
11489 11579 11617 11621 11657 11681 11689 11717 11777 11783 11801 11867 11897 11
933 11939 11953 11969 11981 11987 12043 12049 12071 12097 12101 12143 12251 1228
9 12323 12329 12413 12473 12479 12497 12569 12583 12637 12641 12697 12713 12809
12821 12893 12907 12941 12953 13001 13007 13049 13109 13121 13151 13177 13183 13
187 13259 13297 13313 13337 13397 13421 13451 13457 13469 13499 13513 13553 1357
7 13613 13669 13679 13691 13693 13697 13709 13721 13751 13757 13763 13841 13859
13873 13879 13907 13913 14029 14051 14057 14081 14177 14321 14369 14389 14407 14
411 14479 14489 14533 14537 14621 14627 14633 14639 14657 14713 14723 14741 1474
7 14753 14759 14783 14813 14929 14939 14969 15017 15053 15131 15217 15233 15263
15269 15289 15313 15329 15359 15377 15401 15461 15527 15551 15583 15641 15731 15
737 15761 15797 15823 15959 16001 16061 16097 16111 16193 16217 16253 16273 1642
1 16433 16481 16553 16607 16619 16649 16673 16703 16763 16811 16823 16879 16889
16903 16943 16987 16993 17011 17033 17117 17183 17191 17299 17317 17351 17417 17
449 17467 17477 17497 17519 17573 17579 17597 17627 17657 17729 17737 17747 1776
1 17783 17909 17921 17929 17977 17981 17987 18041 18043 18049 18121 18143 18169
18191 18229 18233 18289 18371 18401 18433 18457 18461 18503 18583 18701 18713 18
719 18773 18869 19001 19031 19069 19073 19121 19139 19163 19211 19249 19289 1937
3 19387 19421 19423 19457 19463 19469 19501 19541 19553 19559 19577 19661 19681
19699 19739 19753 19889 19937 19979
597
?
```

A much more efficient function is

```
check(r)={w=component(factor(r-1),1)~;v=select(s->isprime((r-1)/s+1,2)==1,w);length(v)==0}
```

"check" is $1$ if and only if $r$ is an "omitted" prime. This gives the following numbers of omitted primes below $10^k$ (In comparison : The number of odd primes below $10^7$ in the last line)

```
? for(k=2,7,q=0;forprime(u=3,10^k,if(check(u)==1,q=q+1));print(k,"  ",q));print(
primepi(10^7)-1)
2  4
3  31
4  311
5  2933
6  27933
7  264514
664578
?
```

Comment: Cool! It might be of interest to count the number of "unomitted" primes between consecutive "omitted" primes.

Comment: $264514/664578\approx39.8\%$ is definitely creeping up in density.